# Linear fit for correlated data

Tags: optimization, covariance, correlation, regression, chi-squared-test

Assume I have a set of data points $(x_i,y_i)$ that I want to fit to some model function $f$ which depends on a couple of fit parameters, i.e. $y=f(x;a_1,a_2, ...)$. Usually I'd define a "chi-square" as the sum over the residuals,

$\chi^2 = \sum_i \dfrac{(y_i-f_i)^2}{(\Delta y_i)^2}$

where the $\Delta y_i$ denote the uncertainties of the data points (due to measurements, Monte-Carlo, etc.) and minimize it using some routine like Levenberg-Marquardt or similar to find the optimal parameters $a_i$.

However, if there is correlations between the data points and I know the full covariance matrix $C$ (calculated, for instance, using the Jackknife method), I'd instead minimize the more general

$\chi^2 = \sum_{ij} (y_i-f_i)\, C_{ij}\, (y_j-f_j)$

which takes the correlations into account. As an example, $C_{24}<0$ would imply that the points $y_2$ and $y_4$ are anti-correlated (perhaps due to being calculated from the same data set). In the special case of no cross-correlations $C = \mathrm{diag}(\Delta y_1^{-2},\Delta y_2^{-2}, \ldots) $ and it reduces to the first equation.

My question now is the following: In the case of a linear regression model, I wouldn't need a minimizer routine, since the best fit parameters can be calculated exactly (see, e.g., Numerical Recipes, chapter 15.2). Is this still possible for the "covariance optimized" $\chi^2$ defined above?